# Referencing a cell from the name of another cell in another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to reference grid coordinates in a report, however I am given map references and then I have to transfer the grid coordinates from the map reference.
For eg:
Worksheet One:
Map reference is D-2 and in the next cell are the map coordinates 703370 - 7750584
In Worksheet 2 I want to be able to type in D-2 and have the cordinates show.There are hundreds of map references, so is it also possible to copy the formula for the whole list?
Microsoft Office Standard 2016

Is this possible?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

2 options: Vlookup  or  index/match
the latter is better
a tutorial for it is here:

[https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/index-match.html][1]
[1]: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/index-match.html

in short it's:
=INDEX( $[your coordinate column] , MATCH( [worksheet 2 cell with ref to lookup] , $[your map references column] , 0)

in the ranges above where i have written a $, hit f4 once you've selected the range
which will turn a1:a100 into $a$1:$a$100

hope that helps